# Do I need to upgrade my branch circuits to CAFCI/GFCI if I move my electrical panel?

Tags: electrical, gfci, electrical-panel, afci

I'm moving my main panelboard as part of a service upgrade.  The panelboard is brand new (i.e. I'm not reusing the old board).

Do I need to add CAFCI/GFCI breakers on the old branch circuits (as would be required for new construction/new branch circuits)?  For example, there's no GFCI on my washing machine branch circuit, but Code requires this circuit be GFCI protected for new construction.  Other examples: there's no AFCI anywhere in the house.  I could go on.

The house is located in Seattle, USA, was built in 1927, and contains a mix of knob and tube, NM (original), and NM-B wiring as well as a bit of armored cable here and there.  Eventually, we'll completely rewire the house, but the previous homeowner just added outlets wherever he saw a "convenient" place to tap into an existing circuit.  That's probably good reason *for* adding CAFCI/GFCI protection, but I'm concerned I'm going to be fighting nuisance trips until I can do a proper re-wiring job.

Answers that cite the relevant Code are appreciated!

Comment: Legacy K and T would make me want to add at least GFCI breakers (cheap) and maybe AFCI/GFCI combo breakers (pricey, but I think worth it for some circuits).

Comment: Are you having the work inspected?  If so, you should ask the inspector. I'd guess that you'll have to bring the panel up to current code, which would include AFCI/GFCI protection.

Answer (score 1):

Depends if by moving the panel requires replacing any wires.

For example, if you're simply moving the panel up a foot without having to replace wires then no, no GFCI or Arc fault protection required.

On the other hand, any time a wire is replaced it generally is required to be brought up to code.  This is common rule for not only electrical but all forms of construction.

Comment: I'll have to extend each branch circuit by about 10-15', so that will be new wire.  At some point the previous homeowner or his electrician ran all the K&T into J boxes, then ran NM to the panel.  My plan was basically to use the existing J boxes, and run a longer length of wire to the new panel.  So, that's probably "new," correct?

Comment: Most cases the old wires are only replaced to the point that is accessible.  In contrast, if walls are removed to expose old wires those need to be replaced.